# MySQL JOIN select user id and all his trasection addition

Tags: php, sql

I have a contacts table and a payments table so i want show a list in which the all users addition of their payments.but no repeat of name.help me

Comment: Please provide query that you have tried.Sample data and desired output would help.

Comment: share structure of both tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, not sure if this is what you are looking for.

```
Select contact.name , sum(payment.amount)
from Contact
left join payment on contact.ID = Payment.ContactID
group by contact.name
```